# Split-horizon on DNSMasq?

Tags: dns, bind, dnsmasq

Is it possible to perform Split-horizon with DNSMasq? I've googled and it seems like it is only possible with Bind9, any advice would be much appericated

Comment: dnsmasq is just a caching resolver, go bind9

Comment: not quite correct.  `dnsmasq` isn't as full-featured a nameserver as, say, `bind9` or `nsd` but it is capable of being an authoritative nameserver.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure dnsmasq to resolve names for a certain domain through a dedicated name server (quoting from [the documentation](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/setup.html)):

> Using special servers.
>
> Dnsmasq has the ability to direct DNS queries
> for certain domains to specific upstream nameservers. This feature was
> added for use with VPNs but it is fully general. The scenario is this:
> you have a standard internet connection via an ISP, and dnsmasq is
> configured to forward queries to the ISP's nameservers, then you make
> a VPN connection into your companies network, giving access to hosts
> inside the company firewall. You have access, but since many of the
> internal hosts aren't visible on the public internet, your company
> doesn't publish them to the public DNS and you can't get their IP
> address from the ISP nameservers. The solution is to use the companies
> nameserver for private domains within the company, and dnsmasq allows
> this. Assuming that internal company machines are all in the domain
> internal.myco.com and the companies nameserver is at 192.168.10.1 then
> the option server=/internal.myco.com/192.168.10.1 will direct all
> queries in the internal domain to the correct nameserver. You can
> specify more than one domain in each server option. If there is more
> than one nameserver just include as many server options as is needed
> to specify them all.

So you can try to add something like...

```
server=/acme.corp/10.1.1.2
```

...to your configuration.

You might not be affected, but anybody trying to configure their dnsmasq on modern desktop systems might soon realise that NetworkManager is spawning dnsmasq. The configuration is clobbered together from files in `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/`.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you answer while you have not understood the question - especially as [split horizon DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-horizon_DNS) is a single Google search away.

Comment: This is a correct answer, whether Frederick knew the terminology or not.

Comment: @ki9 no, it's not; you cannot serve different results to clients in different networks

Comment: Yes, you can serve different zonefiles for different ACLs.